# what may cause an app to run on some devices and not on some others?

Tags: android

I often hear that some applications run on some models or brands, but the same application crashes, or doesn't run at all on some other devices.

I really cannot understand. Isn't android APIs the same on all devices running THE SAME VERSION of android? Have you got any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Some device's have different native API implementaions, for example AudioRecord may support only 22050 Hz on some devices even if documentations say that 44100 is supported across all devices.
- Your app may crash because of different performance, for example if some device measures layout slower, but you expect layout to be laid-out in the other thread at specific time - you may get crash.
- Some devices don't have Geocoder built-in, so it will crash.
- Some devices have less memory and can crash with OutOfMemoryError if your app is heavy on memory.
- Some devices don't have Google Play Services. If you rely on them without checking, it will crash.
- Some devices have no camera / accelerometer / barometer / bluetooth / etc and  if you didn't check for the availability before using it, it will crash.

There are a lot more to say, but you will have to look at the crash logs to track the particular issue.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of little things.  Not enough memory on some devices.  Bugs in the drivers for hardware.  Subtle assumptions that the hardware will react in certain ways.  Hardware not as capable-  for example some touch screens can detect only 2 fingers, some can do 10.  And of course they may be using slightly different versions of Android with/without some bug fixes, or with some custom changes.  However 99% of the time your app will work, it really isn't that big a deal unless you're pushing the hardware.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful guides.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yeah, the android version and apis are the same.
but think about different hardware on the phone.
one might have a camera, and one might not.
1 have 256mb of ram, and the other 2g.
same for screen sizes and dpi.

so its not only software problem..